# Selenium RC too slow even for simple tests

Tags: selenium-rc

Does anybody have any idea why **Selenium RC server** takes a long time to run tests? A simple test of just opening a webpage (php) and asserting the title takes an unforgiving 4 minutes!
The tests are being run on Ubuntu server and using headless (XFrame Buffer) Selenium RC server. Does the fact that XFrame Buffer is being used make a difference?

Comment: I tried using simple test to debug the problem. the current test i am using is simply opens a webpage and asserts the title but even this tests run for about 4 mins... the start method in Selenium.php seem to take a minute or to and sometimes getTitle() method is struck for a long time. the tests to finish however after a long time.any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Downgrading Testing_Selenium to 0.4.3 from 0.4.4 helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur suggestion.it did solve the problem.the test take less than a minute now.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate to this problem is to use "Selenium" bundled within the PHPUnit package.
i have currently moved my code from using Testing_Selenium package to using selenium interface within PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Is the web page local or remote?  The simplest answer could be that you're connecting to a slow host, or the connection between client and server is slow.

Can you provide any more details about the server configuration that's running RC? As far as I have read Xfvb should be faster.

Comment: Thank you reed for your answer.

Comment: Thank you Adam for your answer.
The webpage is very much local ( we connect to localhost/ourpage )

Answer (score 0):

There's something about your environment that's causing this.  We run a suite of about 700 tests several times a day, and most of the (sometimes very complex) tests complete in under 30 seconds.  Our environment is Windows running in an EC2 virtual machine with everything on the same machine - database, browser, appserver, test scripts, and Selenium.  We avoid some network delays that way, but the flip side is that we have heavy CPU and memory pressure.

Comment: I am not particularly sure what could be wrong with the environment which is causing this.The server is able to take in heavy cpu or memory pressure as they are applications running on it.

Comment: i have checked the system utilization when the tests are running or other wise (using vmstat) and most of the time i see the system in not over loaded or anything.
the underlying webpage being tested is in PHP. is selenium known to perform slower for php code?